# XmlElement array as Children of specific node

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I have the following code:

```
var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
var docNode = xDoc.CreateElement("Document");
```

Which generates the following XML:

```
<Document>
</Document>
```

On the other side, I have a method that returns an array of XmlElements, the main idea is to insert those elements as children of the previous Document element created.

```
var childNodes = GetNodes(); //this method returns XmlElement[]
```

Now the question: is there a way to directly assign all the items or the array XmlElement[] as children of the node without looping through the array?, I mean something like this:

```
docNode.Children(childNodes); //THIS IS NOT WORKING, JUST GUESSING
```

Language: C# 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there's no direct way to do this, so I did this:

```
var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
var docNode = xDoc.CreateElement("Document");
foreach (var element in returnDocumentData)
{
    if (docNode.OwnerDocument != null)
    {
        //need to import the element because it's being generated from a
        //different xmlDocument context
        var importElement = docNode.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(element, true);
        docNode.AppendChild(importElement);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps somebody too.